Use local and sync storages in chrome/firefox browser extension
Is it possible to use a mix of local and sync storages on a Chrome browser extension/add-on?
Local will store a large set of data but sync will be a smaller subset that can be synced across multiple devices.
browser.storage.local
  .get([a,b])
  .then(() => {
    browser.storage.sync
      .get([c,d])
      .then(doSomething, onError);
  }, onError);

I was thinking something like above but for some reason, it doesn't seem to execute the code (when I add console.log)
Has someone tried something similar to this?
Appreciate any response/help.

Yes you can do it and the code you've shown works normally (assuming you fix it to actually use the result of the first call), so you need to provide debugging details and MCVE.

(Comment form of my previous answer from 2024-10-15 04:10:15Z, before I had rep to comment) When I run your code as a background script (adding a console.log to output the result of storage.local.get and defining doSomething to be console.log, as well), I get console output. So I'm not sure what you mean when you say: "I was thinking something like above but for some reason, it doesn't seem to execute the code (when I add console.log)" Are you bombing before you get there?

For some reason, the ext uses its own console window so I was looking at the wrong console window. All good. Thanks all.
